# Strong equivalence of norm and its square root

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to check whether there is no $\alpha > 0$ such that, $\forall x, y
\in [ 0, 1]$, $\alpha \sqrt{| x - y |} \leqslant | x - y |$.

**My attempt**: Assume $\alpha$ exists then, for $x \neq y$, $\alpha \leqslant
\sqrt{| x - y |}$. This should hold for every $x \neq y$ in $[ 0, 1]$, thus
$\alpha \leqslant \inf_{x \neq y} \sqrt{| x - y |} = 0$. Contradiction because
$\alpha > 0$.

Is my reasoning correct? Is there a simpler proof that does not use contradiction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct and about as simple as it's possible to get; you'll inevitably have to use contradiction since you're trying to give a proof of *non*-existence of $\alpha$.